# Create child class object from parent class static method typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have two classes `User` and `Model` User class extends Base class Model.

```
class User extends Model {}
```

Model class has a static method `createFrom`

```
static createFrom<T, K>(this: new () => T, data: K): T {}
```

I can call this method like

```
User.createFrom<User, DataType>({...data_of_DataType});
User.createFrom<User, OtherDataType>({...data_of_OtherDataType});
```

As you can see I have to define `User` in generics everytime when I have to add generic `DataType` I want something like this.

```
User.createFrom<DataType>({...data_of_DataType});
```

Is it possible without removing generic `T` from `createFrom` because I need return type in `createFrom`

**Update**.

Here is [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBkEsCMCgDMCuA7AxgF0ge2aVOA3AUwCd0ARAQ3UoEll0sBhAG0oGd2AKVF9gLlCVkATwA0oACbVKg4SICUAb1ig1oEHkKl0UmaEgMseNp1BZoAKyHJJoEkXSISyVeodOXJ9gG5YAX1hNAFFbCBhYWF4OdlAAWSxJIhZQFXVQdhpMVDwHaiIAMRIsAFsAHgAVCQBpAD4udAALSAFQZCIAd1AuBVAAXlrQKr0aQWqFQQrUt3S1D2dcfGRiMioaekZWGIbm9glpGgU-dMDAqNNYgFV2UlAiAA90IltYhKSUpTPYQyeSeEpUERQLQ1pRUmclpkRrJgaD%20uC-EEwLRdB0sCQANagFiQDFApotWDXUgAOlQeSeRVKZWJJAkIJk9QOlCOkSRwNAHWEunYpUczWQAHNsbj8bsiTcSGSKYViuUGTQmTIjkA) you can check it

**update 2**

```
// Lib
function convertDataIntoClass(cls: any, data: any){
    // convert data into class obj and return
    return cls;
}
// End Lib

class Model {
    static createFrom<T, K>(this: new () => T, data: K): T {
        return convertDataIntoClass(this, data);
    }
}

class User extends Model {}


interface IData {
    id: string;
}
interface IAnotherData {
    name: string;
}

const anotherData: IAnotherData = {name: "id-123"};

const data: IData = {id: "id-123"};

// It work like this
User.createFrom<User, IData>(data);

// You can't create with other data
User.createFrom<User, IData>(anotherData); // Error, this is what I want

// Create user with other type
User.createFrom<User, IAnotherData>(anotherData);


// I want something like this
User.createFrom<IData>(data);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBkEsCMCgDMCuA7AxgF0ge2aVOA3AUwCd0ARAQ3UoEll0sBhAG0oGd2AKVF9gLlCVkATwA0oACbVKg4SICUAb1ig1oEHkKl0UmaEgMseNp1BZoAKyHJJoEkXSISyVeodOXJ9gG5YAX1hNAFFbCBhYWF4OdlAAWSxJIhZQFXVQdhpMVDwHaiIAMRIsAFsAHgAVCQBpAD4udAALSAFQZCIAd1AuBVAAXlrQKr0aQWqFQQrUt3S1D2dcfGRiMioaekZWGIbm9glpGgU-dMDAqNNYgFV2UlAiAA90IltYhKSUpTPYQyeSeEpUERQLQ1pRUmclpkRrJgaD%20uC-EEwLRdB0sCQANagFiQDFApotWDXUgAOlQeSeRVKZWJJAkIJk9QOlCOkSRwNAHWEunYpUczWQAHNsbj8bsiTcSGSKYViuUGTQmTIjkA)

As you can see in example if you explicitly define the data type then you can't use anyother data type. For example `User.createFrom<User, IData>(anotherData)` if you define `IData` you can't use `anotherData` init and vice versa. This is what I want just I don't want to pass `User` everytime in `createFrom` generic I simple want something like `User.createFrom<IData>(data)`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/m0yrqW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any explicit type parameters. TS is smart enough to infer both the class and data type from the call signature:

```
User.createFrom(data);
  // Model.createFrom<User, IData>(this: new () => User, data: IData): User
```

Comment: But I have to mention what kind of data I'm going to pass to avoid mistake.

Comment: It makes no difference to the type whether you are explicit or not - if you don't mention it, TS picks it up from context. Adding explicit types everywhere is not how you get type safety from your code. The type safety comes when you try to use the result somewhere it is not expected.

Comment: If you explicitly mention type then you can pass anther type of data, this is what I want please check the updated question **update 2**